# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command 'idevice_id -l' exited with code null

Tags: appium-ios, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am facing an error while recording using Katalon Studio:

- katalon studio version 6.1.5
- Appium: 1.13.0
- xcode: 10.1
- macosx: 10.13.6

Check screenshot for the full error log:

[image]